# ¿Hay una diferencia entre "restaurante" y "restauran"?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones

¿Cuál es la diferencia, si la hay, entre "restaurante" y "restauran"?

He escuchado la palabra "restauran" algunas veces, pero recientemente la vi en una señal también:

[image: Restauran colonial]

¿Son sinónimos?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Restaurante**: Establecimiento público donde se sirven comidas y bebidas, mediante precio, para ser consumidas en el mismo local.

**Restorán**: lo mismo, pero derivado del francés "**restaurant**", que más o menos bien pronunciado, suena parecido (*rɛstərənt*)

**Restauran**: *Restaurant* pero escrito como lo pronuncia un hispanoparlante que no sabe francés ("*restaurán*") ni se preocupa de poner tildes. En el caso de la imagen también podría ser que el pintor, viendo que *RESTAURAN* ya ocupaba el 60% del muro y todavía debía escribir *COLONIAL*, decidió suprimir la *T* y encoger el resto por falta de espacio. Bien mirado es una opción lógica, ya que pocos la pronuncian. :-)

En otro contexto "restauran" también podría ser un correcto presente de la tercera persona del plural del verbo *restaurar*, pero obviamente no en este caso.

Comment: La RAE (Real Academia Española) no admite *restorán* como vocablo, ni tampoco *restauran* salvo como tercera persona del plural del presente de indicativo del verbo restaurar.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : Creo que la respuesta deja claro que "restauran" es, en este caso, una incorrección. "Restorán" es , diga lo que diga la RAE, muy usada y de formación correcta.

Comment: @leonbloy: Tienes razón, hice la búsqueda mal en el diccionario de la RAE (es un poco tiquismiquis con las tildes). Restorán está aceptado por la rae como sinónimo de Restaurante: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=restaur%C3%A1n

Comment: Sólo por aclarar, en España "restorán" no se usa mucho, pero efectivamente es un extranjerismo ya admitido, mientras "restauran" es un barbarismo léxico y fonético con el mismo origen, pero incorrecto  mientras su uso y abuso no lo convierta en parte del idioma.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's misspelled. The right spelling for restaurant is [*restaurante*, *restaurant+ or *restorán*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=restaurant).

The difference is that *restauran* is a misspelling of *restaurante*.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not much of an answer to the question. Is there any difference between the two words?

Comment: The difference is that "Restauran" is a misspelling of restaurante

Comment: As far as restaurante and restorán they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The word `restauran` derives from the verbe "`restaurar`" ([to restore](http://dle.rae.es/restaurar)), and corresponds to the [third person in plural](http://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol-verbo-restaurar.html):

```
Ellos / Ellas restauran.
```

In this case, I agree with Ares, it's misspelled. The word "`restauran`" is not related at all with `[restaurante][3]`.

I believe that most of the 'deformations' of some words in spanish are generated by:

- The way people is used to talk on a certain region or country.
- The lack of vocabulary/education on the language (I don't mean to be discriminatory)

People tend to omit some syllables at the end of the words when they talk, thus it wont be surprinsing at all to hear `restauran` from time to time, or even see it misspelled like in this case, when refering to a `restaurant`. It happends all over latin america (on eastern Bolivia, for instance, people tend to omit the 's', or even change it for a 'j' when speaking, so it's very common to hear things like 'pue' or 'puej' insted of 'pues').

The two words you ask about are not related and are probably just the result of what I mention (what I say is just based on my empirical experience).